# Upgrade from Prism wp8.1 to Prism 6 UWP

Tags: prism, uwp

I make WP for 8.1 application UWP. It uses the library of Prism.MVVM, Prism.StoreApps and Unity.
What library the new version should I download from Nuget (or compile from source) make everything work with minimal changes?
You can make a list of what methods/classes are named differently in the new version?
Sorry for my English (Bing Translate :-))

Answer (score 1):

Prism 6 doesn't support WP 8.1.  It only supports WPF, WIndows 10 UWP (Universal Windows Platfomrs), and Xamarin.Forms.